# How to update mouse position with useState

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to push mouse position value into array and update on state.
If I stop moving mouse then the array get reset, so I want to store all values continuously with useState.

```
    const [route, setRoute] = useState("");

    let positionArray = [];

    const getMousePosition = (e) => {
        const position = {
            x: e.offsetX,
            y: e.offsetY,
        }
        positionArray.push(position);

        //setRoute([...positionArray, position])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', getMousePosition);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('mousemove', getMousePosition);
    })
```

I don't know what to do.. or is there any better idea? Thanks!

Comment: It is better to set the default state to ```[]``` here: ```const [route, setRoute] = useState([]);``` This will prevent any errors that might arise when you use functions like ```map```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! it was just simple mistake, I should've just

```
setRoute(route => [...positionArray, ...route])
```

Comment: When updating arrays I would suggest to ***always*** use a functional state update to ensure you always update from the previous state and not the state closed over in callback scope, i.e. `setRoutes(routes => [position, ...routes]);`.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly Update/Set the state.There Is no need of array. `route.x` have  x offset value and `route.y` have y offest value.

```
const [route, setRoute] = useState("");



const getMousePosition = (e) => {
    const position = {
        x: e.offsetX,
        y: e.offsetY,
    }
  

   setRoute(position);
}

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', getMousePosition);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('mousemove', getMousePosition);
})
```

Comment: Thanks but if you do that way, you can't store all positions when you move your mouse. you just updating one object on route state.